# Check if every row of a matrix has a one element

Tags: matlab, matrix

For a certain binary matrix, I need to check if every row have at least one 1 as an element
Ex:
[1 0 0;0 1 0;1 0 0] returns true
[1 0 0;0 0 0;0 1 0] returns false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `all` and `any`:

```
all(any(M, 2))
```